# Kakashi's chakra nature

Tags: naruto

I haven't read the manga, but I have been watching the anime. Kakashi seemed to use earth style before inclining to lightning style. 

So can a shinobi learn to master a chakra nature other than his chakra nature easily ? Or does Kakashi have both the chakra natures ?

Comment: I can't tell if your asking if Kakashi has two chakra affinities or if it's about being able to use multiple nature type. Please consider clarifying your body and *especially* your title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kakashi Hatake's natural affinity is towards Lightning Release. Being a Jonin (now Kage) level ninja, he is adept in using multiple releases.

Kakashi's nature affinity was confirmed to be Lightning Release by the use of Chakra paper, in episode 55 of *Shippuden* (courtesy of @krazer):

[image]

Earth Release is not his natural affinity, and hence he had learned it (along with other releases).

> So a shinobi can learn to master a chakra nature other than his chakra nature easily. Is that so?

Yes, shinobi are capable of using multiple chakra natures (eg: Jonin, Kage, Missing Nin, etc.):

> Jōnin are generally able to use **at least two types of elemental chakra**, proficient genjutsu, and decent taijutsu skills.
>
> <sub>source: [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dnin)</sub>

It is common (but not easy) for shinobi to master elemental chakra apart from their affinity.

In Kakashi's case, he was able to use the following Releases:

<kbd>[image: Bust of an unknown god]

 [**Kakashi Hatake**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake)</kbd>

From [Nature Transformation article](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation):

> Shinobi have an easier time learning to create and control chakra natures that match their affinity, although even then it may take any number of years. **Shinobi are not limited to the nature they have an affinity for, and it is in fact common for jōnin to have mastered two natures**. Although it is technically possible to master all five natures, it is very rare because of how much of training is involved; Hiruzen Sarutobi, Hashirama Senju, Tobirama Senju, Mū, Kakashi Hatake, and Orochimaru are the only shinobi known to have done so via normal means.

Comment: Thanks, I got this doubt because Kakashi often uses the earth style. The latest filler episode shows kakashi using some earth style jutsu to beat obito to win the price. Again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Although Kakashi can have any chakra nature because of his Sharingan, his two chakra natures are lightning and earth. We know this, because Kakashi himself creates Chidori, a lightning style technique, and he performs some kind of earth jutsu before he acquires the Sharingan.